# Size of array exceeds maximum object size in CPP

Tags: c++, c++14

Recently, i'd faced this error while solving a variation problem of knapsack. Can anyone please suggest some way to get rid of it.

```
const int n=105, w= 1000000005;
int val[n], ans[n][w];
int weight[n];
```

Error: size '4000000020' of array 'ans' exceeds maximum object size '2147483647'.

Comment: Yes, use a `std::vector`. Arrays are typically stored on the stack, and that has a lot less space than the heap, which is where `std::vector` stores its data.

Comment: Same problem persists

Comment: Ok, add the `vector` code to the question, and explain that it has the same issues.

Comment: _"Same problem persists"_ No it doesn't. Spend more than 2 minutes on the attempt. Learn how to initialise a vector. Hint: it's not with `[]`.

Comment: Also that's almost certainly the wrong way to solve the task. Think about how much storage you're using!

Comment: ok thanks. but is there any effective approach with the given constraint.

Comment: The purpose of the task is for you to work that out. :)

Comment: 1<=n<=100 |     1<=w<= 1000000000

Comment: okay i understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your doing there is creating Tera Bytes worth of memory allocations. Usually you do those type of allocations in the heap (using vectors like `std::vector<int> val(n);` and `std::vector<std::vector<int>> ans(n, std::vector<int>(w));`). But still, are you sure you need that much of memory? After all your talking about as much as 105,000,000,525 integers.

Comment: ok. but the constraint are given in that way. do i have alternative?

Comment: @shreyakjain How about we forget about the maximums and just add elements as we go on? Because sometimes the constraints are an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please suggest some way to get rid of it.

- Option 1: Make the array smaller so that it doesn't exceed the limit.
- Option 2: Target a system with a higher limit.
- Option 3: Allocate the array dynamically. A simple way to do that is to use `std::vector`.